# Getting 400 bad request when I use "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" and "Authorize"

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, dotnet-httpclient, antiforgerytoken

I'm using asp.net core in the server side and xamarin in the client side.I use JWT token and I want to validate forgery token at the same time.

This is my client side code :

```cs
 public async Task<string> PostAsync(object model, string url)
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var handlerhttps = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseCookies = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                CookieContainer = cookieContainer
            };

            var clientPage = new HttpClient(handler: handlerhttps)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(uriString: Application.Current.Resources[index: "Domain"] + "/api/token")
            };

            var pageWithToken = await clientPage.GetAsync(requestUri: clientPage.BaseAddress);
            var verificationToken = await pageWithToken.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                UseCookies = true
            })
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler: handler) {BaseAddress = new Uri(uriString: url)})
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(name: "RequestVerificationToken", value: verificationToken);
                    if (Application.Current.Properties[key: "Token"] != null)
                    {
                        var token = Application.Current.Properties[key: "Token"].ToString();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme: "Bearer", parameter: token);
                    }


                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value: model);
                    var content = new StringContent(content: json, encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                        mediaType: "application/json");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri: client.BaseAddress, content: content);
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is when I use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and `[Authorize]` in the server side at the same time, I get 400 bad request.

But when I remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, It will authorize without any problem.

When I remove `[Authorize]` , I don't get 400 bad request and it validate forgery token successfully.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` it will add a input field with a 'difficult to guess' code:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8PXv-VNSuRBLvOlUgHlQcf4p8B29vW6EKn4ENesSgHR79kWTvbnQ9a1Taj90b-e66-79H7Nx5ljHnvPbwqfSNqHMRMaBkoRKGsTxtbZZlq0rSl2zbGK2aKpPQc0qnoNuRehSNhP097P5-Vlp-3OSPYdIqLQJSqIsPDaQsEOXsNU4qIIDrj-tIhqk5EW9tTYc6g">
```

Anyways, even if you add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` it wouldn't conflict. However you cannot decorate the 'first' controller action with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, only the final one with will get the POST.

Example:

**Action 1**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("SpecialSignUp")]
public IActionResult Index([FromForm] string email)
{
    // TODO : code in here
    return View(email);
}
```

*Users will be redirect to above action through a POST.*

Let's say that the view above displays a form with the email field pre-filled and other fields to be filled.

If you decorate it with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` you will get a **400 (Bad Request)**. Removing it, all will be fine.

**Action 2**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous] // It could be [Authorized]
[ActionName("SpecialSignUp")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> LaunchSignUpAsync([FromForm] SpecialSignUpViewModel model)
{
    // TODO : Code in here
    return RedirectToAction("OtherActionX", data);
}
```

*Form will be posted by the above View*

Now all it's working, no conflict is happening anymore. If you respect that sequence, it will work for you!

I had the same issue, and it was happening because I decorated the 'Action 1' with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` as well.

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: I will test your sequence solution in the future , Thank you but I searched in the past few days and I faced a question in stack that someone asked : "Is it necessary to use forgery token when we use non cookie session token (like JWT )", and someone answered that : "No , When someone can access your session token , forgery token doesn't help your security and its useless". 
Is it true?
It means using ValidateAntiForgeryToken and Authorized with together, is useless and Authorized only is enough .

Comment: Is there another action before PostAsync? Like a page users requests which will have a form with the '__RequestVerificationToken'? You can not hit that end point (PostAsync) at first without the token been generated first.

Comment: I get the verification token from this action in server side and as the same as you see in my question Xamarin code side,I send it to server by header ...
 
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ForgeryToken()
        {
            var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(httpContext: HttpContext).RequestToken;
            return new ObjectResult(value: tokens);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but got it resolved by adding "RequestVerificationToken" on my request

My controller code (sample)

HttpPost("SignOut")
Authorize  ==> using JWT
    ValidateAntiForgeryToken
*/

Comment: see my code , I also added RequestVerificationToken to my request but I got 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

A **CSRF prevention mechanism**, the server verifies the CSRF token by comparing the value of the token in the request header with the value of the token in the cookie.

make a new file and add this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Project.Decorators
{
public class CSRFAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // The idea is to compare token from cookie and http header
        bool res = false;
        string? csrfTokenHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"];
        var cookies =  context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
        string csrfFromCookie = string.Empty;
        foreach (var i in cookies){
            if (i.Key == "XSRF-TOKEN")
            {
                csrfFromCookie = i.Value.Trim();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(csrfFromCookie + " COOKIE \n");
        Console.WriteLine(csrfTokenHeader + " HEADER");
        if (csrfFromCookie == csrfTokenHeader)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(true);
            res = true;
        }
        if (!res)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
}
}
```

while making a request for example

```
  fetch("/your_url", {
  method: "get",
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-XSRF-TOKEN": getCookieValue("XSRF-TOKEN"),
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "token"
  },
}).then(res => console.log(res));

function getCookieValue(name) {
// Search for the cookie name followed by an equals sign
var regex = new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + name + "\\s*\\=\\s* 
([^;]*).*$)|^.*$");
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(regex, "$1");
return cookieValue;
}
```

Then in your endpoint

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("your_url")]
    [CSRF]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Test() {
        return new JsonResult(Ok());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation advises to use **AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken** instead. Switching to AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken did resolve my issue. I recommend it as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#automatically-validate-antiforgery-tokens-for-unsafe-http-methods-only